# what is the Timestamp?

Tags: ros, timestamp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1-Can someone please explain what exactly is the timestamp that is sent along with every message regardless of the data type ? This number is huge and its in the range of 4.7x10^18 .

2- For synchronization between GPS and for example IMU, can we simple look for the closest Timestamp and regard them as one ?

Thanks,

Naz

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189867/what-is-the-timestamp-?/) by [Naz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19964/naz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS messages timestamp is taken from your system, which is `unix epoch time`.

Check [Unix epoch time](http://www.epochconverter.com/) here.

For synchronisation look  [message_filters](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters)

Documentaiton of the datatypes are at: http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Time and http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Time

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahubers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10876/ahubers/) on 2014-08-12**:
Also, if the workstation and the device are significantly off, you can sync the two with [chrony](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo/Post-Installation%20Setup). Just mentioning because it took me too long to figure out...